# scroll hangs with bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I made a dropdown-menu. As you can see it is scrollable because of the overflow-x:hidden.

In IE9 it works as expected. But when I try it in Chrome, you can scroll till the bottom, and if you scroll a few times more to the bottom, the list will hang for a second and scrolls only then to the top.

```
  <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" 
style="display: inherit; max-height: 200px;width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;">
    <li>
      <a>Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 7</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 8</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item 9</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vwCIau4STpJjWkVJxcar

Comment: Everything seems to be ok. Can you further explain your issue?

Comment: It only happens sometimes when I scroll to the bottom, and then scroll a few times more down. When I want to scroll up (without moving the mouse), the scrolling hangs. But when I move the mouse, I'm able to scroll again.

Comment: Yep, when you spam scroll to the bottom and then try to go up it sometimes hangs.

Comment: FF and IE don't have this bug. Seems Chrome-specific

Comment: If you can't get this to work: Scroll down, hold your mouse above the `item 8` then try to scroll more down, then try to scroll up which doesn't work. Feels like a bug.

Comment: I created a chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=828751#c1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is confirmed and assigned in Chrome. Thereby closing this question.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=828751